# Enabling Wifi or USB Debugging on locked phone without USB Debugging

Tags: android, wifi, adb

I've got a problem with my Android phone. It's locked by 'Too many pattern attempts'.

How can I enable WiFi or USB Debugging on it?

---

More Info:
Phone is not rooted, USB-debugging on phone is disabled, WiFi on phone is disabled, Phone model: Samsung Galaxy S2 (GT-I9100).

Answer (score -1):

The million-dollar answer here is that you can try putting a **prepaid SIM card** in it and that will automatically disable airplane mode to activate. While that is underway, use your Google account to unlock your device.

If you don't care about data on the phone (you make regular backups) you can just factory reset it.

If you **do** need the data, you'll need to remember what Android version you had installed on the phone. If you can't remember, meditate, do therapy, or research on Google until your remember what Android version you had installed. Search for i9100 stock firmware updates with the correct version number and find one on XDA or SamMobile. **Download the right file** and you won't lose **any** data on the device. You'll need to use Odin to flash, or possibly just a micro-SD card if it's a factory .zip. (I did this method successfully on my Note 2 when I flashed recovery while not knowing that my bootloader was locked. It was a hard-brick and I had not made any backups assuming that I would be able to use my brand new custom recovery to make a backup. Worst day of my life.)

I hope this helps you out, if it doesn't, look at [this very detailed answer over on Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35848/101950) and try the 6 or 7 methods listed there.

Comment: Maybe the reason why the detailed answer exists at another `SE` site - because the question belongs there as well?

Comment: Not necessarily. The question falls under the scope of the `adb` tag, which has 3 thousand S/O questions linked to it.